# How do I set up this Java code to add +1 to multiple letter grades when after the user provides a set of numbers?

Tags: java, user-input

Whenever I input a series of numbers, the program only takes the value of the first number into consideration when concerning letter grade. How do I fix this?

Also, how do I record the highest number and lowest number entered by the user?

```
Welcome to the grader-ator!

Enter a grade from 0-100 or enter a negative number to quit.

100

90

80

70

60

-1

Total number of grades is: 5

Number of A's: 1

Number of B's: 0

Number of C's: 0

Number of D's: 0

Number of F's: 0

Highest Score: 0

Lowest Score: 0

Average Score: 80
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //forces the end of the program after calculation
        boolean end = true;
        //Creates a holder for the number of letter grades
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int C = 0;
        int D = 0;
        int F = 0;
        int HighScore = 0;
        int Loser = 0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the grader-ator!");
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a grade from 0-100 or enter a negative number to quit.");
            // Gets the grades from the user
            int grade = keyboard.nextInt();
            // If the grade is between a certain threshold, the number of letter grades is increased
            if (grade >= 93)
            {
                A++;
            }
            if (grade < 93 && grade >= 85)
            {
                B++;
            }
            if (grade < 85 && grade >= 77)
            {
                C++;
            }
            if (grade < 77 && grade >= 70)
            {
                D++;
            }
            if (grade < 70 && grade >= 0)
            {
                F++;
            }
            int average = 0; //Placeholder for the average
            int numberOfGrades = 0; //This keeps track of the number of grades that has been entered in
            while(grade >= 0) //Keeps program running as long as input > 0
            {   
                average += grade; //Adds the grade to the average.  Also this is the same as saying average = average + grade
                numberOfGrades++;//increments the grade counter by 1
                grade = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
                    average /= numberOfGrades; //Finds the average of the numbers
                    System.out.println("Total number of grades is: "+numberOfGrades);
                    System.out.println("Number of A's: "+A);
                    System.out.println("Number of B's: "+B);
                    System.out.println("Number of C's: "+C);
                    System.out.println("Number of D's: "+D);
                    System.out.println("Number of F's: "+F);
                    System.out.println("Highest Score: "+HighScore); //what to put here
                    System.out.println("Lowest Score: "+Loser);  //what to put here
                    System.out.println("Average Score: "+average);
            //ends the program
            }while (end = false); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should step through this code by hand to find the error.  It's pretty obvious but also a basic part of debugging/creating algorithms.  Another idea: break the program into smaller methods that are easier to debug.

Comment: Fix this ---> `do{...}while(end=false);` TO `do{...}while(end!=false);` and insert a condition to coerce end=false based onsome condition!

Answer (score 0):

I see now. I placed the "if" statements too early in the code. They should look like this.

```
while(grade >= 0) //Keeps program running as long as input > 0
{   
    average += grade; //Adds the grade to the average.  Also this is the same as saying average = average + grade
    numberOfGrades++;//increments the grade counter by 1
    grade = keyboard.nextInt();
    // If the grade is between a certain threshold, the number of letter grades is increased
    if (grade >= 93)
    {
        A++;
    }
    if (grade < 93 && grade >= 85)
    {
        B++;
    }
    if (grade < 85 && grade >= 77)
    {
        C++;
    }
    if (grade < 77 && grade >= 70)
    {
        D++;
    }
    if (grade < 70 && grade >= 0)
    {
        F++;
    }
```